# Google Now Event Reservation showing differently on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, google-schemas, google-now

We are using the google event reservation schema [Basic event reminder without a ticket](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation) to trigger a google now card.  We've noticed that the behavior differs in iOS from Android where the iOS version of Google Now shows a "Manage reservation" button on the card and the Android version just shows a link to the "Email from {Our Email}" which opens the email which triggered the card.  Is there any way to force the Android Version to show the "Manage Reservation" button instead of "Email from..." button?

EDIT:  See example markup below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are testing it using the basic Event reservation markup.

In order to get the "Manage reservation" on the action button, you have to add modifyReservationUrl property for the schema markup.

Check all the properties you can add to this markup [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation).

Also find the screen shot which shows the action button as "Manage reservation" in Android device.

[image]

Comment: I'm 100% sure the modifyReservationUrl is set in the markup of these emails as I've checked it several times and the Manage Reservation link is showing up in the iOS app, within Gmail , and also within the new Google Inbox (text says "Modify Reservation" in Gmail and Google Inbox).  It is missing from the Android Application however and is instead showing a "View Email" link.

Comment: Please add the markup you are testing in the question. I can try testing. Thanks!

Comment: I can include a screenshot with portions of the markup blacked out as it contains information I'd rather not display publicly such as our testing site URL.

Comment: Any idea why I'm seeing this behavior?  I've reproduced this countless times and I'm completely lost on why this is happening.  I've added the markup from my email to the question.